# MahApps.Metro - can't set TextBox ClearTextButton font family

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I've changed the default font of every `TextBlock` in the project by setting:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="somefont"  />
</Style>
```

and in text box style (to preserve the icon of the clear button):

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="controls:TextBoxHelper.ButtonFontFamily" Value="Marlett" />
</Style>
```

but the latter style has no effect and still so I'm getting the letter 'r' instead of the `x` on the clear text button

Is this the expected behavior? Or I am the one doing it wrong?

Is there a way of keeping the clear text button's icon right while keeping the general style of the `TextBlock`?

Comment: Setting a style for TextBlock in App.xaml which affects all of these is NOT recommended. FontSize, FontFamily, etc. should always be set only on the base controls which uses TextBlocks inside like TextBox or other ones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the "Key" property for your style with the desired type.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBlock}" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="55"/>
</Style>
```

Then it will be applied to all objects of the specified type by default.

Comment: Setting a key property will prevent applying the style for all the project. I can't just put the key in every text block, I can't reach some `TextBlocks` to put the key on.

Comment: @Majed DH, It can be placed only in the resources of those blocks in which you need to redefine the style.

Comment: Setting a style for TextBlock in App.xaml which affects all of these is NOT recommended. FontSize, FontFamily, etc. should always be set only on the base controls which uses TextBlocks inside like TextBox or other ones.